# What is the best way to store and search through class objects (in PHP)?

Tags: php, oop, optimization, search

I've around 80 instances of this class called Items and would like to efficiently search the objects by their ID or NAME.

```
<?php
class Item
{
    public $id;
    public $name;

   //methods
}
?>
```

I'm using PHP5.

Comment: I would think that a simple foreach loop would be about as efficient as you should care to get.  Anything else would probably cause unnecessary overhead or wouldn't be worth your time.  I'm assuming you're asking this in context of a problem you're trying to solve.  Are the classes you're working with extremely large?

Comment: yeah a foreach loop would work fine. Item class is around 70 lines of code, fairly small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no duplicate names or IDs:

```
$ids = array();
$names = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $ids[$item->id] = $item;
  $names[$item->name] = $item;
}
```

If you have duplicates (of names; I imagine there are no duplicate IDs by definition) then you need to work out how to handle that. You could store all the duplicates under one key (so the value becomes an array of matches).

Or do you mean a more sophisticated search? If so, a simple variant might be to break up the item name into words and/or phrases and then index them accordingly into an array.

Comment: is $items an array that contains references to objects? I wanted a simple search and the code you provided would do the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would think about making an ItemIndex class;

this would allow you to maintain an arbitrary number of
independent indexes, overloading the comparison and
search functions as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 80 instances, it really doesn't matter which option you use. Even if your search is N squared, I don't think it's worth it to invest time into a performance optimization here. Do the simplest thing and then profile; if it's horrible, only then consider increasing the complexity of the implementation to make it faster.